# Typescript React Framer Motion Components not visible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

Am trying a very simple framer motion application but the simple component is invisible for reasons I cannot understand. Below is my code

Index tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(

    <App />

 );
```

My component file Coldust.tsx

```
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'
import {FC} from 'react'

 const Coldust : FC = () => {
   return (
    <div>
    
       <h1>FRAMER</h1>

       <div>
       <motion.button className="help">HELP</motion.button>
      </div>
   
    
     </div>
  )
 }

 export default Coldust
```

App.tsx

```
  import './App.css';
  import Coldust from './components/Coldust';

  function App() {
    return (
     <div className="App">
       <Coldust/>
 
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

Am trying to run this very simple application but the HELP button is invisible when I add the motion keyword to the button tags. If I remove the motion keyword, then the button is visible. What am I missing?

Below is my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
"@types/node": "^16.11.43",
"@types/react": "^18.0.15",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.7.4",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
```

What am I missing? I have deleted the index.css and app.css, could this be the problem?

Comment: Try giving the motion component an initial state. This is one way to add it https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#variants

Comment: <motion.button className="help" initial="visible" >HELP</motion.button>  this failed if this is what you meant. its weird that the h1 tag is invisble too...

Comment: Delete the import css statements as you said you deleted those files aswell

Comment: Deleted the imports, no change